# Issues with fullpage.js down arrow

Tags: javascript

Why is clickable down arrow for fullpage.js not initialising?

HTML

```
<div class="contentDiv">
<img class="arrowDown" src="downarrow.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrowDown {
animation: bouncing 2s infinite ease-in-out;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
height: 50px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -25px;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.arrowDown').click(function () {
'use strict';
$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
});
```

Any suggestions as to why this isn't working would be much appreciated,
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to import [**jQuery Library**](https://code.jquery.com/).

Add this to your **< head >**, just before you import your **js** file.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

Make sure that you put your function inside `$(function(){   });`

```
$(function(){
    $('.arrowDown').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
    });
});
```

---

Also, if in any case, you are using `fp-normal-scroll`, I sugest you don't.
[That's why](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2485)

Comment: I have imported jQuery I just didn't think it was relevant to show whole html, thanks tho